# Modify or extend com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity in Google Tango Project

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to create a plugin that creates android main activity in `Unity3d` but `Tango sdk` uses `com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity` as Main activity.

Is there a way to modify `com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity` or extend it?

I am unable to find its package so I am unable to extend it.
It is essential for my plugin to run in main activity.